# Why blank lines can speed up in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

```
...
group by customer_id, name
     
having June>= 100 and July>= 100
```

The only difference is with a blank line between `group by` and `having` or without.
The one with blank line uses 691ms and the one without 1104ms, why it speeds up? Thank you.

Comment: which one did you run first? becase this could be a caching thing

Comment: It does not make sense every query running once for comparison.If you want to do benchmark between two queries, you need to run multiple times.For eliminating `caching` influence, you need 2 databases with same configuration and same data to test the speed.

Comment: I tried the one with the blank line first, then I realized that there is a blank line so I deleted it and ran again. Turned out it ran much slower. So I added the blank line, it came out with a faster result. That's why I am so confused.

Answer (score 0):

Which one you tried first. Seems you executed same query twice and second time, you got response faster. If so, then it's because of cache.

Comment: I tried the one with the blank line first, then I realized that there is a blank line so I deleted it and ran again. Turned out it ran much slower. So I added the blank line, it came out with a faster result. That's why I am so confused.

Comment: And sometimes with or without comment-lines can also impact the speed. I'm wondering why. A SQL beginner has many non-mainstream questions.